# How to Embed Calendar in html 5?

Tags: javascript, html

Can a calender be embedded into a website without using scripring language?
It can be done using java script but i am not sure about html

Comment: You can make the calendar out of HTML. ;)

Comment: depends on what the calendar is supposed to do.

Comment: The calender is suppose to let a user choose date which automatically places the chosen date into the textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, how can I add a date picker to a form via HTML5... Use the poorly supported `<input type="date">`. For more information http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-date

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use HTML5 date controls. Taking a look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime though shows that there is a serious lack of browsers implementing them, and standardization is not the best.

Still, the base markup is pretty easy:

```
<input type="date">
```

I would still recommend something like the jQuery UI Calendar control, though.